# juniper ssg320 intrazone configration issues Close - AGE OUT

Tags: firewall, openvpn, juniper

We have one main office and another small office that holds only 5 people. We have recently setup OpenVPN on our main office and created a bridged vpn between our main office LAN and a windows 2003 server sitting in the small office. The windows 2003 server has 2 NICs one it uses to interface with the main office which has network 192.168.0.0 /20 and another it uses to talk to the local network on 192.168.16.0/24

In the  main office we have a juniper SSG320 firewall but in the small office we have no firewall at the moment. The computers in the main office can now ping and access resources on the windows 2003 server in the small office and beyond including resources on the 192.168.16.0/24 network but when we try the otherway around , computers beyond the windows 2003 server can ping any machine in the main office but if they try to access any shared file in the main office or intranet machine or anything on this network then it fails.

We have looked at the juniper firewall and we have even setup some policies that allow traffic from the other network however, we are getting Close - AGE OUT and Close - RESP on the firewall log.

Any help would be highly appreciated.